# PayPal IPN always returning invalid

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am testing my IPN listener using PayPal's IPN simulator. Everytime I send the IPN it returns 'INVALID'. I can't figure out why. As best I can tell my raw post data and the data I send back to PayPal for validation are identical. The only difference being URL encoding and the added `cmd=_notify-validate`.

Here is my raw post data:

```
residence_country=US&invoice=abc1234&address_city=San+Jose&first_name=John&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&mc_fee=0.44&txn_id=923817247&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&custom=xyz123&payment_date=07%3A44%3A50+31+Oct+2013+PDT&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&item_name1=something&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&tax=2.02&address_name=John+Smith&last_name=Smith&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&verify_sign=ADrwWMGU4CgA.e78xLpNtVihnEe2AKdWo1wY-lMkTec9.xajg4zK.uvs&address_country=United+States&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&notify_version=2.4&txn_type=cart&test_ipn=1&payer_status=verified&mc_currency=USD&mc_gross=15.34&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&item_number1=AK-1234&address_state=CA&mc_gross1=12.34&payment_type=instant&address_street=123%2C+any+street
```

and my validation data:

```
cmd=_notify-validate&residence_country=US&invoice=abc1234&address_city=San%252BJose&first_name=John&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&mc_fee=0.44&txn_id=923817247&receiver_email=seller%252540paypalsandbox.com&custom=xyz123&payment_date=07%25253A44%25253A50%252B31%252BOct%252B2013%252BPDT&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&item_name1=something&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&tax=2.02&address_name=John%252BSmith&last_name=Smith&receiver_id=seller%252540paypalsandbox.com&verify_sign=ADrwWMGU4CgA.e78xLpNtVihnEe2AKdWo1wY-lMkTec9.xajg4zK.uvs&address_country=United%252BStates&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&business=seller%252540paypalsandbox.com&payer_email=buyer%252540paypalsandbox.com&notify_version=2.4&txn_type=cart&test_ipn=1&payer_status=verified&mc_currency=USD&mc_gross=15.34&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&item_number1=AK-1234&address_state=CA&mc_gross1=12.34&payment_type=instant&address_street=123%25252C%252Bany%252Bstreet
```

The code I used for my listener is pretty much the same as the sample code PayPal provides at https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples with only a few small modifications to make it work in my specific server environment.

Any ideas why this is not validating?

Comment: Are you decoding the data before encoding it again? Look at the street on both strings, it looks like it is being encoded twice.

Comment: Nice catch. That was it. the line which was supposed to be decoding the string was actually encoding. It must have just been an incorrect autocomplete that I missed. Thanks. If you post your response as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: How can I get my IPN raw post data. I want to compare it to my validate data @DavidNguyen

Comment: @FarrisFahad under IPN logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string isn't being decoded prior to being encoded ;)

Comment: I have same problem, Can  you explain how you resolve the error ?

Comment: @TejasMehta the data must be returned in an HTML encoded string so if you are HTML decoding it make sure you are HTML encoding it again.